# What determines the amount of inertia of matter?

Tags: inertia

what factors would increase or decrease inertia, i.e. require more or less energy to change the velocity of matter from what is currently required all else being equal?

I have heard of mach's principle but that seems to not be accepted. What other explanations are there that are more accepted as correct for this?

Comment: Inertia simply means that you need to add energy to get a body moving. What is your specific problem in understanding this fact?

Comment: @safesphere is the question clearer to you now? thnx

Comment: Yes, it is more clear now. The answer is energy. Inertia is a measure of the total energy of a body (per $E=mc^2$). The more energy a body has, the more energy you need to add to get it moving faster (inertia).

Comment: @safesphere do you know of a source i can study this relationship further? thanks.

Comment: I'd suggest searching the web for "inertia of energy" to find a source that works best for you.

Comment: @safesphere is not it that you exchange one question with the other? "what factors would increase or decrease inertia?" after your explanation becomes "what factors would increase or decrease energy?"

Comment: @physicopath The factors that would increase or decrease energy are adding or removing some energy.

Answer (score -2):

If you draw a sphere in the 3D Euclid's space you have to do something to change the location. You have to delete it and draw a new one because the Euclid's space does not allow moving points.
If you draw a space-time curve in space-time continuum, you must force the force to move it to a new location.
However, my answer is a bum because I am not a scientist and do not tell anyone that I told you.